# A persistent alternative for std::type_info::name() in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a library which persists the state of C++ objects to disk. Since the objects are defined by the end user, I use `std::type_info::name()` to get the object name as part of the filename to link the persisted data to corresponding objects. However, according to the [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name):

> const char* name() const;
>
> Returns an implementation defined null-terminated character string containing the name of the type. No guarantees are given; in particular, the returned string can be identical for several types and change between invocations of the same program.

`std::type_info::name()` does not guarantee the same value for the same type if application restarted. Worse, it even cannot guarantee distinct names for different types. And [`std::type_info::hash_code()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/hash_code) is similar.

So, **how can I get a distinct name/id of a C++ object that survives application restart**, at least on the same operating system and architecture?

Comment: The standard clearly promises you nothing. If you want a promise from something other than the standard, then all major implementations give you such promise.

Comment: Have you looked into [std::type_index](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) yet?

Comment: Write your own function template to do so (take the type as template parameter and specialize it for every type)

Comment: Your description of problem does confuse "object name" with "type id". It smells like logic error in your whole concept of serialization. Read FAQ https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization then study some serialization libraries (like boost serialization or protocol buffers). Or even better just use the real things.

Comment: @n.m. Thank you for that information. I think that help a lot! This should be easy to guarantee by the compilers.

Comment: @M.M Yes, this should work. But I want to offload that burden from the end users.

Comment: @ÖöTiib I have a spinlock guarded static counter to distinguish each of the objects of a type. Each object will be written in distinct files as long as type_info.name() gives me the guarantee.